# Eloquent JavaScript string concatenation syntax

Tags: javascript, string, string-literals

So this is from the *Eloquent Javascript*. I am trying to figure out why the return find has "(" + history + " + 5)" instead of "(history + 5)"???

Here is the code snippet:

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

The result:

```
console.log(findSolution(24));// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Comment: `"(history + 5)"` is a string literal.  Try that; it's not what you want.

Comment: Looks like you need a break and a pair of fresh eyes in the morning perhaps :P Also, welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: The new interpolation syntax makes this a bit easier to read : `\`(${history} + 5)\``

Comment: Not sure what the difference is then between "string literal" and whatever " + history + " is. This is just my second week with JavaScipt. :(

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Finds the sequence that results in the "target." The sequence being adding by 5s and multiplying by 3s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So difference between "(" + history + " + 5)" and "(history + 5)" is

"(" + history + " + 5)"

```
"("  --> String
history  -->Number
"+5)"  -->String
```

Now if you combine these variable using + it will work like concatenation
so `"(" + history + "+5)"` will give you (5+5) as String

But `"(history + 5)" -->String`
will be like (history + 5) as history will be not a variable now its a string literal

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm still not sure why, but I hope that eventually I come across an explanation in Eloquent JavaScript on this... is there a specific term for this?

Going by " + history + " instead of the the string literal way?

Comment: It's called _string concatenation_.

Comment: understand the power of  " "